# regex: any string between two slashes first of them is prefixed with a defined string

Tags: javascript, regex

I'd like to get the talker name of some mp3s files paths such as the following:

```
/assets/audio/James_Lee/001.mp3
/assets/audio/Marc_Smith/001.mp3
/aasets/audio/blahblah/001.mp3
```

In the previous example we note that each talker name is surrounded by two slashes where the first of them is prefixed with the word *audio*. I need a pattern that matches names like the example above using javascript.

I tried at http://regexpal.com/ :

```
audio/.*/
```

but it only matches `*audio/The_name/*` where I need `*The_name*` only. The other thing I don't know how could I use such patterns with javascript `replace().`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This will get your the name: `(?<=\/assets\/audio\/).*(?=\/)`

Here's the regex in use: http://regexr.com?34747

**Considering Javascript, you could do this:**

```
var string = "/assets/audio/James_Lee/001.mp3";
var name = string.replace(/^.*\/audio\/|\/[\d]+\..*$/g, '');
```

Comment: @Kent - How passive aggressive :-) Yes, I just realized that Javascript was in use.  Working on adjusting the answer.

Comment: @Daedalus could you please regard its usage with replace() method of the javascript string object?

Comment: @Kent - I figured, but you know sometimes these comments can get down right catty :-)

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
var str = "/assets/audio/James_Lee/001.mp3\n/assets/audio/Marc_Smith/001.mp3";

var pattern = /audio\/(.+?)\//g;
var match;
var matches = [];
while ((match = pattern.exec(str)) !== null){
  matches.push(match[1]);
}

console.log(matches);

// If you want a string with only the names, you can re-combine the matches
str = matches.join('\n');
```

Comment: I don't want all the paths string I just need to check one of them, multiple paths in the example is just a matter of example.

Comment: @sємsєм Sorry, you mean you want a final string with just the names? I'm not sure I follow.

Comment: In other word I mean str = only one path.

Comment: @sємsєм So in your example with three strings, what would your expected output be?

Comment: @loganfsmyht I just deal with one string at time.

Comment: This is helpful if you want to get some value after a value in the url

like /bla/123/bla2/345

say you want the value after bla2

Answer (score 0):

how about this?

```
str.replace(/.*audio\/([^\/]*)\/.*/,"$1")
```